Drizzle-ORM findmany return null from a non empty column
The same query as for the other table but seems not to work.

Table with the function and a trigger to populate k_value column
SQL query returns correct data:



Column "k_value" is populated on trigger using a simple function
Drizzle query returns a null value for that column:

const games = await db.query.games.findMany({
    orderBy: (model, { desc }) => desc(model.name),
  });
  console.log(games);


JSON output:


Here is the function and a trigger from Supabase (where I host the database).
BEGIN
    -- Takes the value from 'bgg_weight', multiplies by 4.8, and stores the result as a rounded integer in 'k_value'
    NEW.k_value := ROUND(NEW.bgg_weight * 4.8);
    RETURN NEW;
END;

and the trigger:

Not sure how to debug :(. I checked the types, and they are all fine. No errors during the build, and no errors in the server console it just returns null :(.
